# mysql php table update

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I have a form that is populated from a MySQL connection. The from names look like this:

```
<td><input type="text" name="Time1[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_newNext['Time1'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>

<td><input type="text" name="Time1Out[]" value="<?php echo htmlentities($row_newNext['Time1Out'], ENT_COMPAT, 'utf-8'); ?>" size="32" /></td>
```

I pass the input arrays to another page, but now I need to combine the array somehow in order to insert them using MySQl. I just can't get the structure right. array_combine doesnt work right and neither does merge. Any help please?

Array from each looks like this:

```
//first array

Array(
     [0]=>apple
     [1]=>tree
     [2]=>rock
     )

//second array

Array(
     [0]=>foo
     [1]=>banana
     [2]=>orange
     )
```

I want the arrays to combine into new arrays based on the key. So the new array will be:

```
Array(
     [0]=>apple
     [1]=>foo
     )

Array(
     [0]=>tree
     [1]=>banana
     )

Array(
     [0]=>rock
     [1]=>orange
     )
```

Comment: Show us your array and how `merge` doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can serialize `$row_newNext['Time1']` and $row_newNext['Time1Out'] before sending it in form and `unserialise()` it on the page you recieve your post data or `implode()` it with some sort of delimiter and `explode()` it later.

[implode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php)

[explode()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.explode.php)

[serialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.serialize.php)

[unserialize()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.unserialize.php)